# Rails 7 Stripe request fails to redirect to stripe payment form Help me interpret the log

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I submit a payment to Stripe I get this result in the log My app's using the rack-cors gem and there's a 'config/initializers/cors.rb' file I was expecting to be redirected to a Stripe payment form page

```
08:11:08 web.1  |   Origin: https://2679755d58ba4a3b92a39174d8656a87.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
08:11:08 web.1  |   Path-Info: /checkouts/create
08:11:08 web.1  |   Access-Control-Request-Method: 
08:11:08 web.1  |   Access-Control-Request-Headers: 
08:11:08 web.1  | Started POST "/checkouts/create?post_id=1" for 108.46.143.31 at 2022-12-23 08:11:08 +0000
08:11:08 web.1  |   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Pluck (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
08:11:08 web.1  | Processing by CheckoutsController#create as JS
08:11:08 web.1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "post_id"=>"1"}
08:11:09 web.1  |   Rendering checkouts/create.js.erb
08:11:09 web.1  |   Rendered checkouts/create.js.erb (Duration: 2.4ms | Allocations: 429)
08:11:09 web.1  | Completed 200 OK in 448ms (Views: 13.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 8543)
08:11:09 web.1  | 
08:11:09 web.1  | 
08:11:09 web.1  | {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"=>"GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS, HEAD", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"=>"", "Access-Control-Max-Age"=>"0"}
```

Form:

```
        <td class="td-styling"><div id="checkout-button"><%= button_to (t 'pay_now'), create_checkout_path(post_id: post.id), remote: true, data: {turbo: false} %></div></td>
```

Controller:

```
class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController

  def create
      @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
          price_data: {
            product: 'prod_Miva1sJtJ29QeC',
            unit_amount: 500,
            currency: 'usd',
          },
          quantity: 1,
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: "https://2679755d58ba4a3b92a39174d8656a87.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        cancel_url: "https://2679755d58ba4a3b92a39174d8656a87.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      })
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
  end

end
```

create.js.erb:

```
var stripe = Stripe("<%= Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:public] %>");
var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');


  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
    // available to this file, so you can provide it as argument here
    // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
    sessionId: "<%= @session.id %>"
  }).then(function (result) {
    // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
    // error, display the localized error message to your customer
    // using `result.error.message`.
  });
});
```

Comment: Its rendering `checkouts/create.js.erb`. So the form has `remote: true` and is being submitted as an ajax request. The controller then renders a `create.js.erb` view - I don't know if you intended to actually have the form submit directly to stripe, do a redirect or a client side redirect or just have no clue what you're doing. Thats about all the feedback we can give without an actual reproducable example. I don't see what this has to do with CORS at all.

Comment: I added the view, controller and create.js.erb Also there's a ```    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
``` in application.html.erb in <head> section

Comment: Do you really want/need to do the JS client side flow? Why not just set `remote: false` on the form and use `redirect_to @session.url`?

Comment: Unless this is a legacy app I really wouldn't use the Rails UJS approach (aka js.erb templates and `remote: true`). Its already obsolete and has always been a very wonky solution.

Comment: Thanks i was following an old example What's the change attributable to? Why did we need to respond .js in the past? Was the api not available or different under legacy ?

Comment: Is it better to pass params to success_url or use stripe webhooks that I have to add on the stripe site?

Comment: How do I update the database without using webhooks that I'd be creating on the stripe site? Seems the obvious way is in the view on my site's success_url page

Comment: Rails UJS has largely been superseeded by Turbo. What I would do is save the order in the database your create method before you actually redirect to stripe and then update the data after the payment process is done (for example with a reference to the payment). Otherwise you're just leaving everything hanging.

Comment: Do you mean then don't bother with webhooks?

Comment: Hadn't people already migrated to react?

Comment: No - react is popular. But its just yet another JS framework.

Comment: You should defineately set up a webhook which ensures that the data in your app is updated after a payment even if the client isn't redirected back. Shit happens. What you shouldn't do is the classic mess where someone goes to rediculous lengths to not save anything until the entire deal is done. Data can be updated even after its inserted.

Comment: Yes That's what I'm doing I'm just setting up to sell classified ads and I insert the row and show it with a pay now button in index view if it isn't paid, where paid will be a timestamp

Comment: Thanks It's ironic at this point i get a cors error That's why I went to develop on cloud9 in the first place I think as I remember Cloud9 runs on port 8080 does cors have a problem with that

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go about this is to the async form submission. You can submit the form as a non xhr request by removing `remote: true` from the button and setting it to `data-turbo: false` as you have already done.

In the controller you can redirect to the `@session.url` returned by Stripe. That removes the need for a JS view template.

Make sure to set status to 303 and `allow_other_host: true`. The former makes sure that the browser does not perform the second request with the original request method (`POST` in this case). Without the latter Rails will not redirect to a host that is different from your Rails app. This is new in Rails 7 and was previously a default.

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

Without async form submission the code could look as follows:

```rb
# Form

 <td class="td-styling">
  <div id="checkout-button">
    <%= button_to (t 'pay_now'), create_checkout_path(post_id: post.id), data: {turbo: false} %>
  </div>
</td>

# Controller 

class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [
        price_data: {
          product: 'prod_Miva1sJtJ29QeC',
          unit_amount: 500,
          currency: 'usd',
        },
        quantity: 1,
      ],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: "https://2679755d58ba4a3b92a39174d8656a87.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      cancel_url: "https://2679755d58ba4a3b92a39174d8656a87.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    })

    redirect_to @session.url, status: 303, allow_other_host: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I made some progress I'm stuck on trying to retrieve metadata from session after session=event.data.object for payment.intent.succeeded Should it be session.metadata.post_id where post_id is my custom metadata?